# purpose of using NSURLConnection while calling xml web-service ..?

Tags: iphone

why we are using NSURLConnection object in xml parsing ie.

for eg:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

and then NSURLConnection delegate methods invoked
like:

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{  
    [receivedData setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{ 
    [receivedData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    if(ObjNSXMLParser!=nil && [ObjNSXMLParser retainCount]>0){
        [ObjNSXMLParser release];
        ObjNSXMLParser = nil;
    }

    ObjNSXMLParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:receivedData];
    ObjNSXMLParser.delegate=self;
    [ObjNSXMLParser parse];

}
```

===============================
But we also get data directly by using: no need to initialize NSURLConnection object:

```
NSData *dt = [NSData DatawithcontentsofURL:urlname];
```

which approach is best ?and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSDATA dataWithContentsOfURL:urlname]` will block your application while it gets the data.

`NSURL` will let you get the data in the background so your UI can still work.

If you don't mind blocking the thread you're on, `dataWithContentsOfURL` is much easier to use. However, if you do that on the main thread you will really annoy the user if the loading takes a long time. They'll think the app has broken!